# Showing percentage complete for Net::Sftp upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-sftp

I'm trying to figure out how to log the percentage complete while executing a Net::Sftp upload. Would like to log for every 10% completed, so something like:

"Upload: foo.txt -> /remote/path - 10 % Complete"

"Upload: foo.txt -> /remote/path - 20 % Complete"
etc.

My code right now looks like:

```
sftp = Net::Sftp.start(host,port,:password => password)

sftp.(local_file,remote_path) do |event,uploader,*args|
 case event
 when :open then
  Rails.logger("Starting upload: #{args[0].local} -> #{args[0].remote} (#{args[0].size})")
 when :finished then
  Rails.logger("Finished with #{args[0].remote}")
 end
end
```